# Replace IP address figures with 'X' letters using sed (preserve character number)

Tags: regex, sed

I have a string containing several IPs. I need to replace all of the figures in all the IPs with the letter 'X' using sed, i.e. `10.135.1.03` will become `XX.XXX.X.XX`.

**UPDATE** String contains not only IPs, but other characters too: both letters and figures. Need to replace only IP's figures. Something like "Received 5 connections from 192.168.1.1, 26 connections from 10.0.0.1, total 31 - Tuesday, 20.09.2012. MessageID: 212.132.15".

Answer (score 3):

```
$ str="10.135.1.03"
$ echo $str | sed -e "s/[0-9]/X/g"
XX.XXX.X.XX
```

or in a scripting context, this is probably better:

```
out=$(sed -e "s/[0-9]/X/g" <<< "$str")
```

not sure why you wanted `sed` btw, `tr` has a slightly cleaner syntax:

```
out=$(tr [:digit:] X <<< "$str")
```

when using bash, even cleaner:

```
out=${str//[0-9]/X}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my string contains not only IPs, but other characters too: both letters and figures. Need to replace only IP's figures.

Comment: @JohnDoe and is there a pressing need to replace every character with one X, or can we replace 123 with X as well, making all ip's X.X.X.X?

Comment: yes, we need to preserve the number of characters, one X for one figure.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would find this very difficult with `sed`. I think this would be much easier with `GNU awk`:

```
awk --re-interval '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}/) gsub(/[[:digit:]]/, "X", $i) }1' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Received 5 connections from XXX.XXX.X.X, 26 connections from XX.X.X.X, total 31 - Tuesday, 20.09.2012. MessageID: 212.132.15
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed, tr and Bash):

```
sed -r 's/\<[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\>/$(tr [0-9] X <<<&)/g;s/.*/echo &/e' file
```

you could cheat and do:

```
sed -r 's/\<[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\>/X.X.X.X/g' file
```